# C# HttpClient - Loading content as webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to make a page execute as if it where in a browser.

The website I'm trying to create automated requests has a couple of hidden input elements that are not set with a value unless the OWASP CSRFGuard token injection system has done so.

```
    private async Task<string> GetSynchronizerToken(FlSession fls)
    {
        string token;
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await this.httpClient.GetAsync(flu.Homepage))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    token = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }           
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If I read the string like this it doesn't load the value of the element.

Comment: Getting a page with *HttpClient* doesn't make the javascripts to execute... You may need a real (headless)browser...

Comment: What is `flu`??

Comment: Do you think there is much I could do to retrieve the tokens without executing the javascript?